# Check if a PHP session is active;

Tags: php, session

Basically what I am trying to achieve is this, the below does not work but you should get the idea.

```
if (session_status() == PHP_SESSION_ACTIVE) {
  show specific icons
}
else
{
  don't show specific icons
}
```

What am I doing wrong. How can I reliably check if a session is started in php 5.4. I have read somewhere that this is the recommended way.

Comment: According to the manual, what you show should work fine. What exactly isn't working?

Comment: You need an ajax call to ping every second

Comment: @Mr.Alien what ..why ajax call ?

Comment: @NullPointer What I initially thought was he wanted to check whether a particular user is in session

Comment: @Pekka Even if a user is logged in and has created a session it still automatically does what is in the else..

Comment: What you show should work. Are you doing this *after* the session_start() call?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[session_status](http://php.net/session-status) is available for PHP v5.4 and later, maybe that's why.

You can try with [session_id](http://php.net/session_id) :

> session_id() returns the session id for the current session or the empty string ("") if there is no current session (no current session id exists).

Just what you need for PHP below 5.4 ! ;)

Answer (score 1):

// You can Create your variable and check, exist it.

For example

```
session_name('My_SESSION_HUMANS'); // Create a unique instance of your session variables
session_start();
if(!empty($_SESSION['my_var']))
{
   // IF Session exist.
}
else
{
   // Oops no Session ?
   $_SESSION['my_var'] = 'Yeahaaah!!!!';
}
```