# Telling a php session's name?

Tags: php, session, forum, phpbb

I installed a pre-built forum on my website and I want (in a diffrent page) to check if the forum's session is active.
Something like :

```
if (isset($_SESSION['forum'])) { echo "Session is active!"; }
```

Problem is - I don't know the sessions name...
Tried downloading some chrome add-ons for session managing but I can't get the name of the session.

Whats the right way of doing this?
Thanks ahead!

Comment: Just to clear any confusion; PHP sessions are stored on the server side, and can only be read by the server, not the client. The Chrome add-ons you've been looking at will probably allow you to save and restore a list of open tabs, but that's not the kind of session you're looking for.

Comment: You have session name = Cookie/Post/GET name. And variable name where session vars are stored. I don't know which one you mean. Can you please state what you would like to use this name for, so we can help you further ?

Comment: Patrick is right. phpBB usage of $_SESSION is one that stores its own session data in the database. Have a look through includes/session.php and includes/startup.php which may help you understand how phpbb session works.

Comment: @nirTzezana is your question answered?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can see the dump of $_SESSION variable

```
var_dump($_SESSION);
```

Answer (score 3):

`session_name()` will give you the session name, that usually is defined in php.ini. By default it is always: `PHPSESSID`. This name is used as cookie name or as POST/GET variable name.

`session_id()` will give you the identifier for the current session. It will be the **contents** of the cookie or POST/GET variable.

Then you have `$_SESSION` that will contain all your session data. use `print_r()` to see what you have stored in it so far.

To know if session vars are set you can also just do `if(isset($_SESSION)&&count($_SESSION))`

Answer (score 1):

try 
`print_r ($_SESSION);`

taht way you'll see all sessions

Comment: Not all sessions, but all data stored in session ($_SESSION variable)

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php 
session_start(); 
print_r($_SESSION);
?>
```

Use this to see which session variables are currently set.

Answer (score 0):

You need to check that the session is currently active, and then that the `forum` key is defined

```
if ( ! ($sid = session_id()) {
    session_start();        // open session if not yet opened
    $sid = session_id();    // get sid as session ID
}

// $sid contains the session ID (in cookie)

if (isset($_SESSION['forum'])) {
    // forum is defined
}
```

See also the answer from [this page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13978513/check-if-a-php-session-is-active)